# How can I choose a different virtual warehouse size for Snowflake with dbt?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

How can I choose a different virtual warehouse size with dbt, depending on how its being run?

For example, run on an XL when executing a full dbt build manually, but default to XS when running a specific model (as in `dbt build --select models/test.sql`).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this with a macro:

```
{% macro warehouse_resize(prod_size, stage_size) %}

  {% if target.name == "prod" or target.name == "prod_backfill" %}
  ALTER WAREHOUSE {{ target.warehouse }} SET WAREHOUSE_SIZE = {{ prod_size }};

  {% else %}
  ALTER WAREHOUSE {{ target.warehouse }} SET WAREHOUSE_SIZE = {{ stage_size }};

  {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

and have it as an on-run-start and on-run-end hook to resize.

(*thx [Emily](https://twitter.com/emilyhawkins__)!*)

---

Update: Check the macro `snowflake_utils.warehouse_size()`:

https://github.com/Montreal-Analytics/dbt-snowflake-utils/tree/0.3.0/